# Java does exponent instead of multiply

Tags: java

```
public class tester
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int n = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for(n = 3;n<=24;n=( 2 * n))
    {
      sum = sum + n;
      System.out.println(sum);
    }
  }
}
```

could someone please explain to me why in this for loop it reads n = n*2 as an exponent and not multiplication

Comment: It does read n=n*2 as multiplication, I printed out the values of n and  it said 3, 6, 12, 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't.  This outputs:

```
3
9
21
45
```

Because:

```
Iteration       n                 sum 
    1     n = 3            sum = 0 + 3 = 3
    2     n = 2 * 3 = 6    sum = 3 + 6 = 9
    3     n = 2 * 6 = 12   sum = 9 + 12 = 21
    4     n = 2 * 12 = 24  sum = 21 + 24 = 45
    5     n = 2 * 24 = 48  (break)
```

Notice how in each iteration, `n` is just multiplied by 2, not calculated as an exponent.

Answer (score 1):

You're not calculating the exponent per sé, you're just calculating it wrongly which results in the exponent.

`n` will be

3, 6, 12, etc

but you use `sum`

```
sum = sum + n;
```

which will basically be

sum = 0 + 3 => 3
sum = 3 + 6 => 9
sum = 9 + 12 => 21
etc

Answer (score 0):

In a for loop:
you set a value, declare a rule, and set a function to be preformed while said rule is true.
In your case, you are adding 'n' to your sum, while n is less than 24, every time multiplying n by 2. The asterisk is used for strictly multiplication in java.

Taking a shot in the dark but did you mean to do:

```
for(n = 3;n<=24;n=( 2 * n)){
   sum = n;
   System.out.println(sum);
}
```

if not, a suggestion is to use +=  or -= like so:

```
sum += n;
sun -= n;
```